# Переопределение ++ как движение по списку c#

Tags: c#

При попытке переопределелить ++ как движение по списку (переход на следующий элемент) вылазиет ошибка "Оператор ++ невозможно определить для Node" В чём ошибка?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace лб5._1._1
{
    public class Node
    {
        public object List;
        public object _Data;
        public Node _Next;
        public Node _Prev;
        public object Value
        {
            get { return _Data; }
            set { _Data = value; }
        }
        public Node(object Data)
        {
            this._Data = Data;
        }
        public Node Next
        {
            get { return this._Next; }
            set { this._Next = value; }
        }
   
    }
   

    class List
    {
        public Node First;
        public Node Current;
        public Node Last;
        private uint size;

        public List()
        {
            size = 0;
            First = Current = Last = null;
        }
   

        public static List operator ++(List l)
        {
           l.Current= l.Current.Next;
           return l;
        }
       
         
        public void show() //вывести в прямом порядке
        {
            Current = First;          
            Console.WriteLine(Current.Value.ToString());
            Current++;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Вам ведь уже [сказали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1212093/220553) что не так, а вы вместо того, чтоб "добить" тот вопрос, задаете его по новой, ну не хорошо так!

Comment: Просто не понимаю как правильно сделать, а подсказать никто не может!

Comment: А чего тут понимать то? Где переопределение вашего `++`? В каком классе? В `Node` или в `List`?

Comment: В классе List..

Comment: Ну так почему вы делаете `Current++;`, где `Current` это `public Node Current;`?

Comment: `Current++` - тип `Node`, верно? А для какого типа у вас `++` оператор? Для `List`! `List != Node`.

Comment: Спасибо мужики,вы лучшие!

Comment: И чего вам было не понятно в: `Ну так вы переопределили ++ для типа List, а пытаетесь применить для типа Node, компилятор абсолютно прав) вы можете создать объект типа List и вот к нему уже применить свой ++`... Ей богу, ну можно было ведь чуточку  подумать...